# Error starting node with forever in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, forever

i have a problem when start node with forever in docker container, if i launch manually works, instead the same command in Dockerfile, when build and start the container, exited. 
The command works in bash:

```
docker run -it container_name bash forever start -c 'node --harmony' /my/path/app.js
```

I tried to put command in Dockerfile but the container don't start

```
CMD forever start -c 'node --harmony' /my/path/app.js
```

Comment: Create a small bash script which starts it for you.  This is what we do.

Comment: as an alternative, use docker restart always policy

Comment: Just curious, why use forever with docker? Why not have docker run node directly?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[Google Group discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-user/PvF8QezcoUw)

`Forever start script.js` runs in the background. To run `forever` in the foreground, try `forever script.js`.

> This starts forever in the foreground, which is what Docker needs. Remember a container is "alive" only as long as the process defined in CMD is up and running. Since forever starts as a daemon, the command itself exits and docker will exit also.

```
CMD forever -c 'node --harmony' /my/path/app.js
```

Comment: Keep in mind though, there's currently **[an open issue](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever/issues/729)** that prevents the foreground-running forever from exiting.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the array syntax:

```
CMD ["forever", "start", "-c", "node --harmony", "/my/path/app.js"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm now trying to use `forever` in docker. This works:

```
CMD ["forever", "src/app.js"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put in your Dockerfile :

```
CMD forever app.js
```